# IIS Application Pool User AppData folder doesn't contain a TEMP folder

Tags: iis, user-profile, temp

I try to host a website that needs the user profile tempfolder due to a requirement to load the User Profile
The User folder created in Users contains an AppData folder, but that in turn doesnt contain a TEMP folder

I tried to add the folder before the deploy, but then the profile folder doesnt exist, and it creates another folder for the profile when it tries to start

One workaround would be to trigger a call which creates the User profile folder, and then add it

But i would like to know if there are any better/cleaner option to do it?

Comment: Have you tried to specify system.web/compilation/tempDirectory and recycle application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my previous sysprepping of the machine, my script ran it as the system account, and that caused a lot of funky behavior!